# count daily visitor of a website in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I know how I can count total number or online number of visitor and now. I want to find number of daily visitors and show it in my page and I search for a code to count daily visitors of my website
i use a query and insert a row to my visitor counter table if there's no row with this day. therefore when  a new visitor open a session, the server must run a select and then insert or update a row for every visitors. 
my query is:

```
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT hitNumber FROM VisitorCounter WHERE lastUpdate =  now ))
       BEGIN 
           INSERT INTO counters (somecols) VALUES(somevalue)
        END
   ELSE
     BEGIN
          UPDATE counters  SET hitNumber =  @currentVisitors  WHERE lastUpdate = now
     END
```

i want to know if there is a way witch need to update a row for all visitors and once insert for each day. because since i add this query to session_start in global.cs file my website load slower.

Comment: what's stopping you?

Comment: so you are asking if someone can give you the code that can display number of daily users on your site from google analytics?

Comment: no i want c# or some code. i want save my daily visitors in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // number of visitor
        int totalNumbers = 0;
        // Database
        string dbConStr = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=Test;Integrated Security=true;";
         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = 
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(dbConStr);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT CounterTable (totalNumbers, day) VALUES (@totalNumbers, getdate())";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("totalNumbers",SqlDbType.Int).Value = totalNumbers;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
```